# RegEx & Powershell: Use Regex to Create Files based on name found in CSV

Tags: regex, powershell

I'm trying to import and process a CSV. From the position 2-4 of the third column, I want to write that line to a file with that identifier.

As an example, from line 1 for "results.csv" I am trying to write to a file named "274.txt" the matching line:

```
10.121.8.84,TRUE,N274SECX9010C5D,3/20/2015 15:48
```

I am somewhat certain my regex maybe wrong. It looks fine and is able to go through sample text in Expresso. However, when added to script, I do not see any results.

***Results.csv:***

```
10.121.88.84,TRUE,N274SECX9610C5D,3/20/2015 15:48
10.77.89.109,TRUE,L186OFFX2K6KMX1,3/24/2015 9:49
10.144.18.135,TRUE,N488FOOD2NK6MB1,3/25/2015 7:20
10.181.92.175,FALSE,,
10.147.86.54,FALSE,,
```

***Powershell Code:***

```
$path = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$Results_File = $path + "\results.csv"

Import-Csv $Results_File | ForEach {
    If ($_ -Match '^.*,\w(?<filename>\d{3}).*') {
        $_ | Out-File -Append "$($Matches.Filename).csv"
    }
}
```

Comment: Your regex is fine, although I'd just keep it simple and remove the `.*`s and end up with: `,\w(?<filename>\d{3})`.

Comment: @Sam: Thanks for the validation of the RegEx. With the change, I still get the same result. I guess the issue is in the code and not the regex as I assumed.

Comment: Yea, sorry I don't know anything about powershell.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should just replace your `Import-Csv` by `Get-Content`

```
$path = Split-Path -parent $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Definition
$Results_File = $path + "\results.csv"

get-content $Results_File | ForEach {
    If ($_ -Match '^.*,\w(?<filename>\d{3}).*') {
        $_ | Out-File -Append "$($Matches.Filename).csv"
    }
}
```

Because the result of `import-csv` gives alist of objects whish is not what you want to parse in your regex.
You can also try the following :

```
Import-Csv $Results_File -Header 'C1','C2','C3','C4'
C1            C2    C3              C4                                                  
--            --    --              --                                                  
10.121.88.84  TRUE  N274SECX9610C5D 3/20/2015 15:48                                     
10.77.89.109  TRUE  L186OFFX2K6KMX1 3/24/2015 9:49                                      
10.144.18.135 TRUE  N488FOOD2NK6MB1 3/25/2015 7:20                                      
10.181.92.175 FALSE                                                                     
10.147.86.54  FALSE
```

And then use `$_.C3` with a different RegEx.

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanation, JPBlanc. I appreciate it.